# Need help building a regex that matches a string only if it has the format of between 1 and 5 percent signs (%) optionally delimited by a colon(:)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now, so I'm hoping someone can help me out or point me in the right direction. The string must start and end with at least 1 and no more than 5 %'s and can be delimited by a colon, anything else should not result in a match. There can also be multiple sets of the groups of between 1 and 5 %'s delimited by colons.

For example:

- % => true
- %% => true
- %:% => true
- %:%:%:% => true
- %%:% => true
- %%%%%:%%%%% => true
- %%%%%:%%%%%:%%%%% => true
- %%%%%%:%%%%%% => false
- %#%%:%#%#% => false
- %: => false
- :% => false
- %::% => false

I think I'm close, but can't really afford to spend much more time trying to figure it out. This is what I've got so far:

```
^[%]{1,5}:|[%]{1,5}$
```

Comment: What about `%%%%%%`, six in a row being the whole string? Since there's no `:`, should it fail?

Comment: Yes, it should fail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regular expression:

```
^%{1,5}(?::%{1,5})+$|^%{1,5}$
```

It will first check to see if there are between 1 and 5 `%` signs, followed by a colon, and then 1 to 5 more `%` signs. If not, it will find 1 to 5 `%` signs again.

The `^` and `$` are used to check if the match is at the start and end of the string, so things like %%%%***%%%%%*** (the match being the italicised bold text) don't end up happening.

Comment: Updated my answer to now work with %%%%%:%%%%%:%%%%%:%%%%% and so on

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
^%{1,5}(?::%{1,5})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/8qMt3c/1

Your alternation isn't correct because it's not requiring `$` on the left option, or `^` on the right option, nor are you checking for the up-to-5 `%`s on the other side of the `:`.

Also note that a character set with a single character is superfluous - just use the single character as a token instead.

The whole optional group `(?::%{1,5})?` means that the initial 5 `%`s may be followed by a colon and up to 5 `%`s, *or* the initial 5 can be followed by the end of the string.

If there can be any number of trailing `:%%`s, then make the final quantifier `*` (zero or more) instead of `?` (zero or one):

```
^%{1,5}(?::%{1,5})*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/8qMt3c/2

Comment: I forgot to mention that the string can contain more than 2 sets of between 1 and 5 %'s, so %%%%%:%%%%%:%%%%% is possible and so on.

Comment: Use the `*` quantifier (zero or more) instead of `?` (zero or one)